# can we use a function call inside a case statement in scala line match like below

Tags: scala

```
line match {
  case st => matchEndWith(b.toString()) //this line works or not
}

def matchEndWith(beg: String): String = {
  for(sa <- bwith) {
    if(!sa.equals(beg)) {
      flag = 0
      i = i + 1
      return sa.replaceAll("""\/""","")
    }
  }
  return sa
}
```

I have written the above code but I am getting an error of unreacheble code in the case line. Please tell me that it is possible in scala or not.

Comment: Can you please format your code?

Comment: I think it's useful to see the rest of the code this pattern matching sits in. Also the exact compilation error would be useful.

Comment: don't use `return` ;)

Comment: it doesn't matter what st is, as it is only here to capture what is in line. It would make a difference if it's surrounded by backticks, or in upper-case.

Comment: what is `bwith`? flag and i are external variables ? Could you please provide the definition of these ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.